# Rotate image using pygame

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I am new to pygame and want to write some code that simply rotates an image by 90 degrees every 10 seconds. My code looks like this:

```
    import pygame
    import time
    from pygame.locals import *
    pygame.init()
    display_surf = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1200))
    image_surf = pygame.image.load("/home/tempuser/Pictures/desktop.png").convert()
    imagerect = image_surf.get_rect() 
    display_surf.blit(image_surf,(640, 480))
    pygame.display.flip()
    start = time.time()
    new = time.time()
    while True:
        end = time.time()
        if end - start > 30:
            break
        elif end - new  > 10:
            print "rotating"
            new = time.time()
            pygame.transform.rotate(image_surf,90)
            pygame.display.flip()
```

This code is not working ie the image is not rotating, although "rotating" is being printed in the terminal every 10 seconds. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`pygame.transform.rotate` will not rotate the `Surface` in place, but rather return a new, rotated `Surface`. Even if it would alter the existing `Surface`, you would have to blit it on the display surface again.

What you should do is to keep track of the angle in a variable, increase it by `90` every 10 seconds, and blit the new `Surface` to the screen, e.g.

```
angle = 0
...
while True:
    ...
    elif end - new  > 10:
        ...
        # increase angle
        angle += 90
        # ensure angle does not increase indefinitely
        angle %= 360 
        # create a new, rotated Surface
        surf = pygame.transform.rotate(image_surf, angle)
        # and blit it to the screen
        display_surf.blit(surf, (640, 480))
        ...
```